# Did Time Magazine publish an article in 1931 explaining how to prepare and roll marijuana?

Tags: quotes, recreational-drugs, media, smoking, marijuana

According to a [Feb 3, 2021 blog entry ("Why Is Marijuana Called Reefer?") of Kushfly](https://kushfly.com/blog/why-is-marijuana-called-reefer/), a medical cannabis company, Time Magazine published an article in 1931 explaining how to roll a "reefer", a cannabis-infused cigarette:

> The term first appeared in print in 1931. An article printed in Time Magazine talked about how marijuana leaves could be dried, ground and than rolled into a ‘reefer cigarette,’ saying ‘These cigarettes are bootlegged under the name of ‘muggles,’ ‘reefer,’ or ‘Mary Warners.’

Did [Time Magazine](https://time.com) publish such an article? A search of Time's website under the [Marijuana tag](https://time.com/tag/marijuana/) doesn't show it, but the earliest article under that tag seems to be from 2016 so it is likely that older articles are not tagged and/or not available on the website.

Comment: I think your title has slightly confused the issue.  The blog says the *Time* article "talked about how" the leaves could be processed, i.e. it mentioned the fact that it could be done.  And as Mark's answer shows, the article did indeed mention that.  Your title seems instead to ask whether *Time* gave specific instructions on how to do it - they did not, but the blog never claimed that they did.

Comment: -1. This question is based on a misreading of the article, not a notable claim that requires skeptical scrutiny. The Kushfly blog never claims that a Time article explained anything, so it cannot be a source for a notable claim, and without it, there is no question here.

Answer (score 5):

Time Magazine published [a short article](https://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,742157,00.html) on September 7, 1931 about marijuana, but the article does not "explain how to prepare and roll marijuana". Instead, it provides a brief description of the plant and how it is used, including the sentence

> Its leaves can be dried, ground and rolled into cigarets, which are bootlegged under the name of "muggles," "reefers," or "Mary Warners."

Comment: Interestingly enough, the [Times](https://time.com/3815347/jazz-marijuana-history/) itself got the date wrong for what year "marijuana" first appeared in their publications.

Comment: @Laurel: Just to avoid confusion, the title of *Time*, the American magazine, is not plural and does not have a definite article.  "*The Times*" is a British newspaper.